# Brake caliper piston larger than brake pad?

Tags: toyota, brakes, brake-calipers, rav4, piston

Upgrading my '17 Toyota RAV4 LE to the 296 rotors, which include bigger calipers and brake pads.

On the new calipers, the piston is larger than the brake pad and im not sure if thats normal? I tried two different brake pads (for XLE/Platinum etc) but the same remains.

I know the pad is backwards in the picture, its to help show it easier [image]